# Javascript Function values pulled from HTML form fields

Tags: cordova, forms, javascript

I am trying to create a HTML system, it creates a .txt form through phonegap.

my HTML elements are as such

**SCRIPT**

```
function Savenote() {
// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("DCC.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log(" ' '");
        writer.truncate(11);  
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log(" ' '");
            writer.seek(0);
            writer.write("Henry Aspden");
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                console.log(" ' '");
            }
        };
    };
    writer.write("some sample text");
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
}
</script>
```

**MY BODY/FORM**

```
  <form>
<input type="text" style="width:100%" name="filename" placeholder="Enter File Name">
<textarea rows="10" style="width:100%" name="notes" placeholder="Enter Your Text Notes Here"></textarea>
</form>
<a href="#" onClick="Savenote()"><h1>SAVE</h1></a>
```

**WHATS MY QUESTION THEN?**
I need the values in my  function to be taked from the form fields... and this is how if possible

Where it says

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("DCC.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}
```

the **"DCC.txt"** section must be replaced by the field **"filename"** (i.e. "DCC.txt" is just for demo purposes). Also, the extension .txt is a constant, so it should be 'filename'.txt if that make any sense?

Where it says

```
writer.write("Henry Aspden");
```

the **"Henry Aspden"** section must be replaced by the field **"notes"** (i.e. "Henry Aspden" is just for demo purposes)

**EDIT NUMBER 1**
Changed to

```
    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("var filename = document.getElementById("filename");", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}
```

with

```
<input id="filename" type="text" style="width:100%" name="filename" placeholder="Enter File Name">
```

results in a syntax error here i think... how can I place this new variable within this existing function??

Thanks

Comment: Tried to say thankyou to everybody, but @ruda.almeida editied it out...

Comment: Relevant to your comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: well I think its polite, and doesn't hurt...

Otherwise it just sounds rude doesn't it?

Comment: The goal of my editing wasn't specifically against you. Althought driven by personal needs, questions and answers aren't specifically for individuals but rather for the comunity. That's why I removed statements such as "I have only a few hours remaining", they are quite personal. "Hopefully someone can help" is implicit in the fact you already posted a question. A signature is not needed because your username already appears on the bootom. And in my opinion the "Thanks" can be provided once the correct answer is provided, in the form of a comment, (...)

Comment: (...) but I suppose it's not that important to remove it and if I went too far when removing it, then sorry. Once again, I have absolutely nothing against you or your question.

Comment: No i get your point. I think I could have been much more general in my question, asking simply how to combine two functions etc, however somewhat selfishly I did want it to be specific to fit my problem... I like to thank contributors, including yourself for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the input elements an id:

```
<input id="filename" 
    type="text" style="width:100%" name="filename" placeholder="Enter File Name">
```

Then grab the element and save it as a  JavaScript variable

```
var filename = document.getElementById("filename").value;
```

Put this somewhere before your function call, then pass the variable to your function:

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    var filename = document.getElementById("filename").value; //gets file name

    fileSystem.root.getFile( //call function 
        filename, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail
    );
}
```

Comment: do I need to change "name" to "id" then>

Comment: scrap that, i just read that you put id="filename" in there, sorry, will try now !!

Comment: it doesnt like the syntax of inputting that into my function...

I will edit question to show..

Comment: can you help me now with this function in there please

`function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log(" ' '");
            writer.truncate(11);  
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                console.log(" ' '");
                writer.seek(0);
                writer.write("Henry Aspden");
                writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                    console.log(" ' '");
                }
            };
        };
        writer.write("some sample text");
    }
`

Comment: where id="notes" should replace "Henry Aspden"

Comment: just trying to add `var filename = document.getElementById("notes").value; //gets file name` just below function line and then changing it to `writer.write(notes);`

Comment: Almost! You need to change the `var filename` to `var notes`. 

The `var` part tells JavaScript you are creating a new variable, the `notes` part is the name of the variable. Each variable must have a unique name. 

When you want to use the stored value, you type `notes` and JavaScript inserts whatever was stored in the variable into your code.

Comment: yeye got that after some testing...

Thanks so much for your help, which were on the subject, if I add a

`function imageClick(url) {
    window.location = url;
}`

to the bottom within my onClick function, will it redirect to the specified URL of the <a href="#"> if i make it obviously a link and not # eg, upload_success.html??